# Orders stopped contracting

Tags: cpq, order

Our CPQ for Service Cloud is no longer creating contracts after orders are activated/contracted.  Just started happening this week.  We have a support ticket open, but wondering if anyone else has seen this or has ideas where to look.  It is not working in Sandbox either.

I've got debug logs enabled, but not sure what I'm looking for.  There is no error displayed when order is activated/contracted.

I exported all of the order item lines along with associated quote line information and don't see anything different between the orders that have been working all along (year and half) and the ones that didn't contract (starting some time last weekend).

I also went through the Audit log looking for any changes that may have occurred between the last order being contracted (1/19) and the start of orders not being contracted (1/22)

Comment: Are you referring to Service Contracts? The package is not expired and users have licenses?